# Autoresizing in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift3

How to write below code in swift. Please help.

```
        UIView* destView = ((UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).view;
        destView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout below code (Swift 3.1):

```
var destView: UIView? = (segue.destination as? UIViewController)?.view
destView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
destView?.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(view.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(view.frame.size.height))
```

Comment: `let destView = segue.destination.view`. No optionals and no casting needed.

Comment: Although you translated the code correctly. why don't you use "destView?.frame = view.bounds" instead?

Comment: @Lepidopteron:  I'm guessing it's because the frame and bounds are not identical if the view is zoomed.